# Win 32 Api привязка кнопок

Tags: c++

Здраствуйте, есть рабочий код в котором я ввожу в строку текст и при нажатии на кнопку он добавляется в список, а так же я могу удалить добавленную строку из списка. В чем заключается проблема. Мне нужно привязать hRadioButton1 к hButtonEddit , а hRadioButton2 к hButtonDeleted. Т.е. hButtonEddit должен работать только с hRadioButton1 и hButtonDeleted соотвествено с hRadioButton2. Как это можно сделать?

```
    #include "stdafx.h"
#include <windows.h>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int window_width = 400;
int window_height = 500;

#define ID_CANCEL  100
#define ID_EDIT  101
#define ID_DELETE  102
#define ID_LIST  103

HWND hEdit;
HWND hRadioButton1, hRadioButton2;
HWND hButtonEddit, hButtonDeleted, hButtonExit;
HWND hList;

string res;

LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc(HWND hWnd, UINT message, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    switch (message)
    {
    case WM_CREATE:
    {
        DWORD dwEditStyle = WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE | WS_BORDER | ES_LEFT;
        DWORD dwButtonStyle = WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE | WS_BORDER | BS_PUSHBUTTON;
        DWORD dwCheckBoxStyle = WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE | WS_BORDER | BS_AUTOCHECKBOX;
        DWORD dwListBoxStyle = WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE | WS_BORDER | WS_VSCROLL | LBS_NOTIFY | LBS_DISABLENOSCROLL;
        DWORD dwRadioButtonStyle = WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE | WS_BORDER | BS_AUTORADIOBUTTON;
        HINSTANCE hI = GetModuleHandle(NULL);

        hEdit = CreateWindow("edit", "", dwEditStyle, 30, 20, 300, 20, hWnd, (HMENU)0, hI, NULL);
        hList = CreateWindow("listbox", NULL, WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE | LBS_STANDARD, 90, 200, 200, 150, hWnd, (HMENU)ID_LIST, hI, NULL);



        char szBuff[255];
        GetWindowText(hEdit, szBuff, 255);
        SendMessage(hList, LB_ADDSTRING, 0, (LPARAM)szBuff);

        hRadioButton1 = CreateWindow("button", "(1)Radio", dwRadioButtonStyle, 30, 50, 145, 20, hWnd, (HMENU)0, hI, NULL);
        hRadioButton2 = CreateWindow("button", "(2)Radio", dwRadioButtonStyle, 185, 50, 145, 20, hWnd, (HMENU)0, hI, NULL);
        SendMessage(hRadioButton1, BM_SETCHECK, BST_CHECKED, 1);


        hButtonDeleted = CreateWindow("button", "Удалить", dwButtonStyle, 185, 110, 145, 20, hWnd, (HMENU)ID_DELETE, hI, NULL);
        hButtonEddit = CreateWindow("button", "Добавить", dwButtonStyle, 30, 110, 145, 20, hWnd, (HMENU)ID_EDIT, hI, NULL);
        hButtonExit = CreateWindow("button", "Выход", dwButtonStyle, 185, 140, 145, 20, hWnd, (HMENU)ID_CANCEL, hI, NULL);
    }
    break;
    case WM_COMMAND:
    {
        switch (LOWORD(wParam))
        {
        case ID_CANCEL:
            DestroyWindow(hWnd);
            break;

        case ID_DELETE:
        {
            int idx = (int)::SendMessage(hList, LB_GETCURSEL, 0, 0);
            ::SendMessage(hList, LB_DELETESTRING, (WPARAM)idx, 0);
        }
        break;

        case ID_EDIT:
        {
            char str[80] = { (char)sizeof(str), 0 };
            int len = (int)::SendMessage(hEdit, EM_GETLINE, 0, (LPARAM)str);
            str[len] = '\0';
            ::SendMessage(hList, LB_ADDSTRING, 0, (LPARAM)str);
        }
        break;

        default:
            DefWindowProc(hWnd, message, wParam, lParam);
        }
    }
    break;

    case WM_DESTROY:
        PostQuitMessage(0);
        break;
    }
    return DefWindowProc(hWnd, message, wParam, lParam);
}

ATOM RegMyWindowClass(HINSTANCE hInst, LPCSTR lpzClassName)
{
    WNDCLASS wcWindowClass = { 0 };
    wcWindowClass.lpfnWndProc = (WNDPROC)WndProc;
    wcWindowClass.style = CS_HREDRAW | CS_VREDRAW;
    wcWindowClass.hInstance = hInst;
    wcWindowClass.lpszClassName = lpzClassName;
    wcWindowClass.hCursor = LoadCursor(NULL, IDC_ARROW);
    wcWindowClass.hbrBackground = (HBRUSH)COLOR_APPWORKSPACE;

    return RegisterClass(&wcWindowClass);
}

int APIENTRY WinMain(HINSTANCE hInstance, HINSTANCE hPrevInstance, LPSTR lpCmdLine, int nCmdShow)
{
    LPCTSTR Class = TEXT("My Window Class!");

    if (!RegMyWindowClass(hInstance, Class))
        return 1;

    HWND hwnd = CreateWindow(Class, TEXT("Dialog Window"), WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW | WS_VISIBLE | WS_BORDER | WS_VSCROLL,
        (GetSystemMetrics(SM_CXSCREEN) >> 1) - (window_width >> 1),
        (GetSystemMetrics(SM_CYSCREEN) >> 1) - (window_height >> 1),
        window_width, window_height, NULL, NULL, hInstance, NULL);

    MSG msg;
    while (GetMessage(&msg, NULL, 0, 0))
    {
        DispatchMessage(&msg);
        TranslateMessage(&msg);
    }


    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Подскажите пожалуйста, я ничего в этом не понимаю...

Answer (score 0):

Если я правильно понял Вам нужно сделать чтобы нужные кнопки становились неактивными или активными при выборе радиокнопок. Ниже текст который это реализует.

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <windows.h>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int window_width = 400;
int window_height = 500;

#define ID_CANCEL  100
#define ID_EDIT  101
#define ID_DELETE  102
#define ID_LIST  103
// Добавить идентификаторы радиокнопок
#define ID_RADIO1  104
#define ID_RADIO2  105

HWND hEdit;
HWND hRadioButton1, hRadioButton2;
HWND hButtonEddit, hButtonDeleted, hButtonExit;
HWND hList;

string res;

LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc(HWND hWnd, UINT message, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    switch (message)
    {
    case WM_CREATE:
        {
            DWORD dwEditStyle = WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE | WS_BORDER | ES_LEFT;
            DWORD dwButtonStyle = WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE | WS_BORDER | BS_PUSHBUTTON;
            DWORD dwCheckBoxStyle = WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE | WS_BORDER | BS_AUTOCHECKBOX;
            DWORD dwListBoxStyle = WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE | WS_BORDER | WS_VSCROLL | LBS_NOTIFY | LBS_DISABLENOSCROLL;
            DWORD dwRadioButtonStyle = WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE | WS_BORDER | BS_AUTORADIOBUTTON;
            HINSTANCE hI = GetModuleHandle(NULL);

            hEdit = CreateWindow("edit", "", dwEditStyle, 30, 20, 300, 20, hWnd, (HMENU)0, hI, NULL);
            hList = CreateWindow("listbox", NULL, WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE | LBS_STANDARD, 90, 200, 200, 150, hWnd, (HMENU)ID_LIST, hI, NULL);



            char szBuff[255];
            GetWindowText(hEdit, szBuff, 255);
            SendMessage(hList, LB_ADDSTRING, 0, (LPARAM)szBuff);

            // Указать идентификаторы радиокнопок при создании окна
            hRadioButton1 = CreateWindow("button", "(1)Radio", dwRadioButtonStyle, 30, 50, 145, 20, hWnd, (HMENU)ID_RADIO1, hI, NULL);
            hRadioButton2 = CreateWindow("button", "(2)Radio", dwRadioButtonStyle, 185, 50, 145, 20, hWnd, (HMENU)ID_RADIO2, hI, NULL);
            SendMessage(hRadioButton1, BM_SETCHECK, BST_CHECKED, 1);


            hButtonDeleted = CreateWindow("button", "Удалить", dwButtonStyle, 185, 110, 145, 20, hWnd, (HMENU)ID_DELETE, hI, NULL);
            hButtonEddit = CreateWindow("button", "Добавить", dwButtonStyle, 30, 110, 145, 20, hWnd, (HMENU)ID_EDIT, hI, NULL);
            hButtonExit = CreateWindow("button", "Выход", dwButtonStyle, 185, 140, 145, 20, hWnd, (HMENU)ID_CANCEL, hI, NULL);

            // Установить начальное состояние кнопок "Удалить" "Добавить"
            EnableWindow(hButtonDeleted, FALSE); 
            EnableWindow(hButtonEddit, TRUE);
        }
        break;
    case WM_COMMAND:
        {
            switch (LOWORD(wParam))
            {
            case ID_CANCEL:
                DestroyWindow(hWnd);
                break;

            case ID_DELETE:
                {
                    int idx = (int)::SendMessage(hList, LB_GETCURSEL, 0, 0);
                    ::SendMessage(hList, LB_DELETESTRING, (WPARAM)idx, 0);
                }
                break;

            case ID_EDIT:
                {
                    char str[80] = { (char)sizeof(str), 0 };
                    int len = (int)::SendMessage(hEdit, EM_GETLINE, 0, (LPARAM)str);
                    str[len] = '\0';
                    ::SendMessage(hList, LB_ADDSTRING, 0, (LPARAM)str);
                }
                break;
            case ID_RADIO1:
                {
                    // Получить состояние радиокнопки 1
                    LRESULT lRes = SendMessage(hRadioButton1, BM_GETSTATE, 0, 0);
                    if (BST_CHECKED & lRes)
                    {
                        // Изменить состояние кнопок "Удалить" "Добавить"
                        EnableWindow(hButtonDeleted, FALSE);
                        EnableWindow(hButtonEddit, TRUE);
                    }
                }
                break;
            case ID_RADIO2:
                {
                    // Получить состояние радиокнопки 2
                    LRESULT lRes = SendMessage(hRadioButton2, BM_GETSTATE, 0, 0);
                    if (BST_CHECKED & lRes)
                    {
                        // Изменить состояние кнопок "Удалить" "Добавить"
                        EnableWindow(hButtonDeleted, TRUE);
                        EnableWindow(hButtonEddit, FALSE);
                    }
                }
                break;

            default:
                DefWindowProc(hWnd, message, wParam, lParam);
            }
        }
        break;

    case WM_DESTROY:
        PostQuitMessage(0);
        break;
    }
    return DefWindowProc(hWnd, message, wParam, lParam);
}
```

Данный текст предназначен только для демонстрации того как это делается. В реальном проекте я бы рекомендовал использовать хотя бы MFC.